# What display and controller to use

Tags: microcontroller, display

So I intend to produce a prototype for idea I am have, this idea works off a screen a a micro board, I do not understand much about the subject but I indent on having a screen (7") which I will be able to plug into a board of some sort, and be able to load a program on to it which will display images, in my head I see it working much like a sat-nav, but I don't have a clue what electronic components that I can use, any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: how... i don't even... Let's say someone suggests a display and controller, what's your next step? Do you have someone to design the board for you? If so, you should _really_ consult that person.

Comment: How do satnavs work then surely there hardware must be availible...

Comment: Google is your friend. Please do some research, then come back with reasonable questions. As it now stands, there are far too many possible answers.

Comment: Satnavs work because engineers come together and design hardware.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called a large mobile phone or small to medium sized tablet. These are readily available with touch screens, batteries and charger ports. Get one with an open operating system such as Android.

[image]

Then you need a programming platform that can create applications to run on your hardware. Some thing like [Qt](http://qt.ie/) might suit your purposes.

Otherwise your question is ridiculous!